# Object assignment and pointers

Tags: ruby, object, copy, variable-assignment

I am a little confused about object assignment and pointers in Ruby, and coded up this snippet to test my assumptions.

```
class Foo
    attr_accessor :one, :two
    def initialize(one, two)
        @one = one
        @two = two
    end

end

bar = Foo.new(1, 2)
beans = bar

puts bar
puts beans

beans.one = 2
puts bar
puts beans
puts beans.one
puts bar.one
```

I had assumed that when I assigned bar to beans, it would create a copy of the object, and modifying one would not affect the other. Alas, the output shows otherwise.

```
^_^[jergason:~]$ ruby test.rb 
#<Foo:0x100155c60>
#<Foo:0x100155c60>
#<Foo:0x100155c60>
#<Foo:0x100155c60>
2
2
```

I believe that the numbers have something to do with the address of the object, and they are the same for both beans and bar, and when I modify beans, bar gets changed as well, which is not what I had expected. It appears that I am only creating a pointer to the object, not a copy of it. What do I need to do to copy the object on assignment, instead of creating a pointer?

Tests with the Array class shows some strange behavior as well.

```
foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
baz = foo
puts "foo is #{foo}"
puts "baz is #{baz}"
foo.pop
puts "foo is #{foo}"
puts "baz is #{baz}"

foo += ["a hill of beans is a wonderful thing"]
puts "foo is #{foo}"
puts "baz is #{baz}"
```

This produces the following wonky output:

```
foo is 012345
baz is 012345
foo is 01234
baz is 01234
foo is 01234a hill of beans is a wonderful thing
baz is 01234
```

This blows my mind. Calling pop on foo affects baz as well, so it isn't a copy, but concatenating something onto foo only affects foo, and not baz. So when am I dealing with the original object, and when am I dealing with a copy? In my own classes, how can I make sure that assignment copies, and doesn't make pointers? Help this confused guy out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of questions in this question. The main thing to know is **assignment never makes a copy in ruby, but methods often return new objects instead of modifying existing objects**. For immutable objects like Fixnums, you can ignore this, but for objects like arrays or Foo instances, to make a copy you must do `bar.dup`.

As for the array example, `foo +=` is not concatenating onto the array stored in `foo`, to do that you would do `foo.concat(['a'])`. Instead, it is making a new array and assigning `foo` to that. The documentation for the Array class mentions which methods mutate the array in place and which return a new array.

Comment: How would I implement .clone functionality in my own classes then?

Comment: The implementation of clone in Foo would just return `Foo.new(self.one, self.two)`

Comment: In this case, inherited `Object#clone` would work as well, because it copies instance variables too.

Comment: `Object#dup` if you want your object not to be frozen

Answer (score 3):

`+` and `-` in `Array` each return *new* arrays filled with the respective content, so `foo += [...]` not affecting `baz` is normal. Try the `<<` operator on `foo` and the result will be `baz` seeing the same change.

I'm not sure how Ruby handles the other thing internally but you might try using `one.clone` and `two.clone` in `Foo#initialize`.

Answer (score 2):

You never deal with a copy. It's the same object in memory, but you just declare 2 references to it: in your first example: bar and beans point towards the same object in memory; and in your second example: foo and baz point to the same array in memory initially.

Check out the 2 picture/drawings, in the Java tutorial page that explains the mechanism (it's the same as in Ruby) and those 2 pictures only, worth more than any explanation in words:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

Basicly ruby is using reference pointer so when you are changing one thing other is also get effected.