# Column_names being deleted when deleting from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I do:

```
name_array = Model.column_names
name_array.delete_if {|name| ["id","created_at","updated_at"].include?(name)}
pp Model.column_names
```

The `Model.column_names` command will return an array without the `id`, `created_at` & `updated_at` column names. It was my presumption that the `name_array` would have the names deleted and not the Model.column_names array.

Rails 3.0.13
Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Here is a similar question with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635156/object-assignment-and-pointers

Comment: iouri Your comment was what I needed. If you want to make it an answer  I will accept.

Comment: If you accept the answer of that link that would be ok with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Array documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) for `delete_if`:

> Deletes every element of self for which block evaluates to true. The array is changed instantly every time the block is called and not after the iteration is over.

So when you delete elements from `name_array`, you are actually deleting them from `Model.column_names` since they're pointing to the same thing.

If you don't want to do that, [duplicate the array](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) before deleting:

```
name_array = Model.column_names.dup
name_array.delete_if {|name| ["id","created_at","updated_at"].include?(name)}
```

Comment: Thank you. Between you and iouri's link it cleared up my issues.

Answer (score 2):

u can also use **reject**

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.reject{|x| x>=2}
=> [1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Dup can help, but there is an restruction. The fact that dup creates 'shallow copy', it has the following non-obvious consequences:

```
> arr = Model.column_names.dup
=> ["id", "name", "klasse", "cars_count", "klasse_id"] 
> arr.delete('id')
=> "id" 
> arr
=> ["name", "klasse", "cars_count", "klasse_id"] 
> Model.column_names
=> ["id", "name", "klasse", "cars_count", "klasse_id"] 
> arr.each &:upcase!
=> ["NAME", "KLASSE", "CARS_COUNT", "KLASSE_ID"] 
> Model.column_names
=> ["id", "NAME", "KLASSE", "CARS_COUNT", "KLASSE_ID"]
```